# Convert hostname to only one IP Address

Tags: c#, winforms, ip-address, hostname

I want to create hostname to IP address and vice versa converter. However I got a problem in which 1 hostname return 2 IP addresses and when I reconvert the IP address to hostname, only one of them return the correct hostname.

Example for convert `CEGN5CG7260FR7.xxxxx.xxx` it return `192.168.X.XX` and `10.132.XXX.XXX` but when reconvert back to hostname, only `10.132.XXX.XXX` return the correct hostname.

This code snip for convert hostname to IP address:-

```
// Convert hostname to IP address
            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostList[i]);
            IPAddress[] ipaddr = host.AddressList;
            // Loop through the IP Address array and add the IP address to IP List
            foreach (IPAddress addr in ipaddr)
            {
                if (addr.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                     ipList.Add(addr.ToString());
                }
            }
            // Display items in IP Address textbox
            foreach (var ip in ipList)
            {
                ips += ip + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            txtIP.Text = ips;
```

This code snip for convert IP address to hostname:-

```
// Convert IP address to hostname
            IPHostEntry IP = Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Parse(ip));
            if (IP != null)
            {
                 hostList.Add(IP.HostName);
            }
            // Display items in Hostname textbox
            foreach (var hn in hostList)
            {
                hosts += hn + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            txtHost.Text = hosts;
```

What I can do to only get and display `10.132.XXX.XXX` IP address and ignore the first one?

Comment: `var ip = ipList.FirstOrDefault(v => v.StartsWith("10.132"))`? O:)

Comment: i'm afraid that will only take those with starting with `10.132.` there is also a list of ip which start with `172.21` and so on.

Comment: whats the output for the other HostName? Is it blank or some other value?

Comment: It's not quite clear why you want to ignore the other IP address. If you want only IP address from a specific subnet then answer from John is enough. Otherwise you could take a first one.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya the output is no host known for the `192.168.X.XX` address.

Comment: @montonero I want to ignore the other since it returns no host known. I wish to only use IP address with the known host when convert it. The first one is the `192.168.X.XX` returns no host known, that's why I need to ignore it.

Comment: Then you'll need to check all IPs and find which one will be resolved back to host name. In my opinion ignoring other IPs is not a very good  practice although I don't know why you need this.

Comment: @montonero thanks for your idea. I also think that it is not wise to ignore others IP. will try implement your idea. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to find correct IP address.

```
 public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
    }
```

Comment: I'm not trying to convert the IP to local hostname.

Comment: Mentioned code is not return hostname from the IP Address, It is returning IP address from the Hostname